# Ancestors' same-name siblings

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<corpus>
    <header id="1">
        <file>
            <info>
                <title id="A" />
            </info>
        </file>
    </header>
    <TEI>
        <header id="2">
            <file>
                 <info>
                     <title id="B" />
                 </info>
            </file>
        </header>
        <header id="3">
            <file>
                 <info>
                     <record>
                          <title id="C" />
                     </record>
                 </info>
            </file>
        </header>
        <header id="4">
            <file>
            </file> 
        </header>
    </TEI>
</corpus>
```

$list is a set of `<title>` nodes.

The depth of `<title>` varies, but is always somewhere under a `<header>`. The depth of `<header>` varies, but its depth from root is always the same for all nodes in a given $list.

Given a $list, I need a for-each loop that loops through headers.

When the only node in $list is title A, I need to loop only through header 1.

When the nodes in $list are titles B and C, I need to loop through headers 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Sorry, but the question in its current form is unintelligible. Please, provide a complete (but as small as possible) XML document and exactly which nodes must be selected.

Comment: Also, there is no `$items` variable defined at all or referenced in the XPath expression ... ???

Comment: I have provided a fuller example and tried to make the question intelligible.

Comment: Good. Have a look at my answer. +1 from me for the now meaningful question.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre! I had overlooked the [1]. Now I get it. Q answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
$list/ancestor::header[1]/../header
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vList1" select=
  "/*/header[1]/*/*/title"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vList2" select=
  "/*/TEI//title"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$vList1"/>
 ====
  <xsl:copy-of select="$vList2"/>
 ====
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "$vList1/ancestor::header[1]/../header"/>
 ====
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "$vList2/ancestor::header[1]/../header"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<corpus>
    <header id="1">
        <file>
            <info>
                <title id="A" />
            </info>
        </file>
    </header>
    <TEI>
        <header id="2">
            <file>
                <info>
                    <title id="B" />
                </info>
            </file>
        </header>
        <header id="3">
            <file>
                <info>
                    <record>
                        <title id="C" />
                    </record>
                </info>
            </file>
        </header>
        <header id="4">
            <file>
            </file>
        </header>
    </TEI>
</corpus>
```

**the XPath expressions are evaluated and the wanted in each case `header` elements are selected and output**:

```
<title id="A"/>
 ====
  <title id="B"/>
<title id="C"/>
 ====
  <header id="1">

   <file>

      <info>

         <title id="A"/>

      </info>

   </file>

</header>
 ====
  <header id="2">

   <file>

      <info>

         <title id="B"/>

      </info>

   </file>

</header>
<header id="3">

   <file>

      <info>

         <record>

            <title id="C"/>

         </record>

      </info>

   </file>

</header>
<header id="4">

   <file>

   </file>

</header>
```